# Complexity of emptiness checking for visibly pushdown automata?

Tags: context-free, time-complexity, pushdown-automata, space-complexity

Visibly pushdown automata [1] are pushdown automata in which input symbol determines whether push or pop operation happens in the stack. Does anyone aware of tight lower bound for their emptiness checking complexity?

[1] Rajeev Alur and P. Madhusudan. 2004. Visibly pushdown languages. In Proceedings of the thirty-sixth annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing (STOC '04). ACM, New York, NY, USA, 202-211. DOI: http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1007352.1007390

Comment: What's the best lower bound you've found so far?  the best upper bound?

Comment: O(n^3) from PDA emptiness checking, as given by Alur. I found no other mention anywhere.

Comment: Also, it is P-complete: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019010004114